# Method keeps returning nil

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays that looks like the following

```
transactions = [{"id"=>"83Z...",
                 "date"=>"2016-05-24", 
                 "amount"=>6.22, 
                 "name"=>"DD/BR #346737 Q35"},
                {"id"=>"jzEo...", 
                 "date"=>"2016-05-24", 
                 "amount"=>8.37, 
                 "name"=>"Yl Statedivision Inc"}
                ]
```

I am running the method below to get an array of just the names (no repeat names) with all numbers removed from the name.

In console it works fine but when I try and run it on my actual app the filtered_names comes back as an array of nil's and causes the method to fail. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
 def transaction_names
  short_list = self.transactions.find_all { |t| Date.parse(t["date"]) >= 90.days.ago.to_date}
  filtered_names = short_list.map { |trans| trans[:name] }
  short_names = filtered_names.map { |name| name.gsub(/\d\s?/, "") }.uniq
  self.trans_names = short_names
  save
end
```

This should return

```
trans_names = ["DD/BR","Yl Statedivision Inc"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original hash has keys that are strings, but you use a symbol to fetch the name. Just change this line

```
filtered_names = short_list.map { |trans| trans[:name] }
```

to

```
filtered_names = short_list.map { |trans| trans['name'] }
```

Comment: Thanks that got it. I missed that. It was driving me crazy!